# How can I exclude small boxes in tree map?

Tags: r, treemap

I have a tree map code in R

```
treemap(df,
        index=c("Account.Name"),
        vSize = "X2017",
        type="index",
        palette = "Reds",
        title="Test tree",
        fontsize.title = 14 
)
```

Here this code generates tree map, but there are many very small boxes which have very small sum(default fun.aggregate) of "X2017" with respect to "Account.Name". Is there a way to exclude these small boxes like putting some limit or something ?

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the aggregation prior to creating the treemap. For example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(treemap)
df_sum = df %>% group_by(Account.Name) %>% summarise(X2017 = sum(X2017)) %>% filter(X2017 > 10)
treemap(df_sum,
        index=c("Account.Name"),
        vSize = "X2017",
        type="index",
        palette = "Reds",
        title="Test tree",
        fontsize.title = 14 
)
```

The above will first aggregate (sum) the `X2017` field by Account Name and then keep only cases where `X2017 > 10` (change this to your desired value). The rest is the same as your code but with the aggregated data frame as the input.

Comment: Excellent, Exactly what I am looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry that I could mark your answer useful (need to have 15 reputation), because this is my first question and I joined now.

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help.